# Disable Access To SQL Server Database Via SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Apologies in advance for the long post, I am trying to be as clear as possible. Is there a way to disable a user / Windows AD group accessing a database via SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)?

I have an desktop application that uses a SQL Server 2005 database. The application runs as the user logged onto the machine (unfortunately we can't change that otherwise this would be simple). The database is permissioned with groups (but it would apply to users as well) to give access to the appropriate schemas and objects that the user requires. The users have (and need) the ability to select, insert, update and delete data to complete their process.

The application carries out a series of validation and auditing steps on the user input to ensure they are entering decent data (and for some additional business processing). A user could open SSMS and make these changes through the query editor avoiding the application completely which is what we are trying to avoid. What I am looking for is a way to stop the users updating the database through any tool other than the application provided.

I have found a couple of similar posts (including [How to disable SQL Server Management Studio for a user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/898380/how-to-disable-sql-server-management-studio-for-a-user)) but these don't quite cover this issue as they work on restricting user access or using different logins.

The only solution I can think of at the moment is to have a set of tables where the user data goes initially and then another process picks this up, runs the application processes on and then puts the data into the master / source tables. Then I could restrict user access to the master tables.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a good scenario for an [application role](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190998%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I hadn't thought about application roles. Unfortunately we can't change the way application connects to the database (it's an externally built system) otherwise this would have been ideal

Comment: If you have no control over the application, then there isn't much you can do. A [logon trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326598(v=sql.90).aspx) could check the application name, but client applications set that name themselves, so you can't trust it. Your best option is probably to work with your supplier to update the application.

Comment: Thanks for replying and apologies about the delay in getting back to you. If it can't be done then it can't be done :). At least we can go back to our auditors with a couple of ideas that get as close as possible.

Comment: Well if you have auditors involved then you should consider a risk mitigation plan using whatever other tools you have. For example, if you already have an automated software asset control system in place you could use it to detect and report on 'rogue' SSMS installations. Or you could use auditing and traces to report on 'unusual' activity. As always, a lot depends on how much effort you are willing - or required - to invest in mitigating the risks.