# Winforms and SQL server windows authentication

Tags: sql, winforms, windows-authentication

Is possible to have windows authentication with connect, read and write rights, but without possibility the user has rights to connect with SQL Management Studio? I want the user has rights to connect and execute queries with his own domain username from an application, but not to connect from SQL Management Studio.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/898380/how-to-disable-sql-server-management-studio-for-a-user ?

Comment: What ever access they have as a user they have in your app or SSMS. What concern do you have?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution which I have succeeded to find is this: Define login only with rights to execute stored procedures, then move all queries to SP. By this way you can connect with SQL Management Studio but cannot list any table or change anything or even see the table/sp names.