# Preventing connections to SQL Server from SSMS

Tags: ssms, ssms-18

I've heard it said many times that the Windows Authentication is preferred over SQL Server authentication when it comes to securing SQL Server, however, this has always struck me as counterintuitive since if a user's Windows Authentication requires them to be able to modify tables, then there's no way to prevent this activity should they log in using SSMS - bypassing the application logic.

I've used server triggers in the past to prevent this but I've also had a couple scenarios where this left us unable to log on to the SQL Server.  I also get that many people would argue that, for this reason, all updates to the database should be done via stored procedures - which isn't an option for us since many of our applications are COTS.

How have others handled this?  Am I the only one who sees this as a problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable SQL Server Management Studio for a user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/898380/how-to-disable-sql-server-management-studio-for-a-user)

Comment: I’ve seen the trigger-based approach before and have used it but we ran into a weird case where it simply stopped working - causing me to lose confidence in the approach.